# after updating to expo 41 TransitionPresets stop working like before

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using `TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS` in my project and after updating to expo 41 the model behavior changed.
after updating it the top part of the model start changing color
here a image before

[image]

and after

[image]

how can i fix it to return transparent as before

Comment: Try :  "headers": [{
      "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      } ]
    },{
      "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css)",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
 "value": "no-cache"      } ]

Comment: As my knowledge of Firebase Hosting .. You cannot do this :(